# CakePHP Update button

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm building a CakePHP-application that people can install on their hosting.
In the meantime I'm still working on the application, so I want people to be able to update it just by clicking on an update button.
From the moment I write new code in a Controller, make new Components,..., I push it up to the "Source-server" and they click on update then they have to have all this updated code on their server as well.
I was thinking to write an exec (command line) that executes a git pull/fetch but not every hosting has git installed, so that's not the best solution.
Can somebody help me out with that?

Thanks in advance,

Aäron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a package system: Your php script will download a zip file that contains all the code from a source, unpack it in a temporary folder, read the meta data file that tells your script what version the plugin or application code is, compare it with the running version, maybe do some security checks like a checksum or if you like to implement that a signature check. When the checks were successful you'll have to replace the existing files with the files from the package.

You could even give the option to do a rollback if you keep the zip of the previous version. Don't forget that your update code needs a way to fire database migrations as well. I would develop a "Package" or "PluginManager" plugin that does all of that. The event system can be used to trigger events when things are installed / deinstalled.

Wordpress does it this way, you might want to look at what it does but I would not recommend to take any of the fugly wordpress code, just use the concept.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! So I think the best way is to not have the update code in the application. I'm going to take a deeper look to how Wordpress does it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You can have the update code of the app itself. Wordpress manages to update itself somehow. I guess there can be some issues doing that on the fly but nothing that can't be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Like joomla , wordpress you can create installation package which  can check the current version and check server version.
   stept2
    after compression it create database and file backup
    step3 download pakedge from server under a temp directory
    step4 replace new lib with older one
    step5 if update successfully then delete pkg from temp directory and delete old file backup
    step6 if fail replace the site sitebackup